# Who and what can lay down suppressive fire?

Tags: battlefield-3

Reading about the classes before the beta started, I had the impression that suppressive fire was a super-power for the Support class.

But since I've gotten the bonus when playing at least one other class, that's apparently not the case. Which has left me wondering why people often write about suppressive fire and the Support class as though they were connected in some way.

So:

- Which weapons can lay down suppressive fire?
- Does the Support class have some bonus for laying it down? Or is it just more associated with the Support class because, given the bipod, they're more likely than other classes to sit still and spew lead?

Comment: I've also gotten suppression fire with nearly every weapon in the engineer class. I suspect it's more of how/where you fire a weapon rather than the gun you use.

Comment: @Andy: Can you edit the title to include the question of what determines the amount of suppression...?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Any class and any weapon can lay down suppressive fire. The amount of suppression achieved depends on 3 things:

1. The proximity of the bullets to the person
2. The size of the bullets fired (bigger bullets, and especially frag rounds and explosives, will achieve more of a suppressive effect, so an smg will have less of a suppressive effect than a sniper rifle)
3. The amount of bullets fired (the suppression effect continues to stack until it reaches the cap, so an smg can be just as suppressive as a sniper rifle, but will require more bullets).

All of this coupled together makes the Support class generally the best class to purposely lay down suppressive fire, as using the bi-pod will make you accurate enough to get close proximity, your bullets are large enough to achieve quite a good suppression effect per bullet and you can fire much more than any other class to reach the suppression cap much more quickly.

With that said, generally, you won't purposely try to lay down suppressive fire much (unless you're in a really good squad who actually communicates and works as a team), you'll generally be taking a few shots at an enemy and a few will miss, causing suppression, and as long as they're at least a little bit suppressed, you'll get the suppression bonus if someone else kills them (they don't need to be very suppressed at all, just enough to cause the screen blur).

Comment: What is suppression, actually? Does just firing at the opponent count, or does he have to stay in cover after you opened fire?

Comment: @Bora, I might be wrong, but I don't think suppression depends on whether and when the suppress-ee is under cover. I'm reasonably sure I've suffered the penalty (blurred vision, worse accuracy, and non-healing) when standing and/or moving, not just when under cover... though once it starts I do try hard to get to cover. :-)

Comment: @AndyGiesler What happens is that the more you move, the faster it goes away, so you can suffer it while running, however it will go away fairly quickly. The best thing to get rid of it, is to look for nearby cover and sprint towards it. It should have dissipated by then.

Comment: So, you're punished for someone missing you?

Comment: @Yatrix Pretty much. But it's fairly realistic, so I think it's a nice addition.

Comment: This game does too much to blind you as it is. I don't need a crappy shot slowing my roll because he can't hit a target. I'm no soldier, but I don't think a bullet missing me would blind me. I can understand maybe an accuracy drop or making my guy piss himself (that'd be funny, you gotta admit), but enough with the damned vision impairment. If it's not the sun, it's a flashlight, if not that, it's a laser and if not that, it's bad shooting by the opposition? If all that blinding is in the game, they need a visor attachment or something to counter it. /endgripe

Comment: I think it is supposed to be less about them "missing you" and more about the fact they are holding you in a position. If you play with a decent headset you can actually hear the shots narrowly miss you and I think in a real life situation knowing you are being shot at and if you move into the open and will get shot you might have a bit of a rush (hence the vision slowed). I like to think of it like in chess having a pawn in the right place to force their king into another direction. Although I do agree that all of the vision impairing measures in the game gets quite frustrating at times

Answer (score 17):

[Someone on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/battlefield3/comments/ne37x/suppression_fire_explained_what_triggers_it_and/) did some testing and found the actual suppression area around a target; firing bullets, a number of them (how many depends on caliber, etc) into the area in red will cause suppression.

Also an official response from one of the game designers:

> Shooting at cover will suppress, if the player is close to the cover. Furthermore the suppression zone is a sphere, which is why you can suppress when hitting the cover. The bullet passing through the zone and the bullet impacting in the zone both have suppressive aspects.

[image: battlefield 3 suppression diaram]

Answer (score 1):

Smoke grenades can cause suppression.

Answer (score -2):

If you take the suppressive perks, you will probably get suppressive kills if you are shooting the spotted person or target.