# What determines Suppression?

Tags: battlefield-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Who and what can lay down suppressive fire?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32139/who-and-what-can-lay-down-suppressive-fire)

As per the title, what determines what is Suppressing fire? And how is it different from being a rubbish aim?

Comment: Supression just makes you move slower

Comment: @MrSmooth: I would disagree, just because I'm asking what determines what is suppressive fire (firing around or near or whatever), but not which weapons have suppressive capabilities

Comment: While your question was different, the answer in the other question answered your previous question.

Comment: id suggest editing the other question to include this one. If the other one had this question in it, i wouldn't have bothered posting it.